# API gateway does not pass cognito token data to AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have made authorizer, tested it with token and it shows values (seen on image). I've put authorizer in Method Request. I've tried various options in Integration Request (see image) to pass user, email to lambda, but all options come to lambda as blank.

log: Execution log for request 15b7bb5d-48df-11e9-b05b-37cbe151f14e Sun Mar 17 18:04:19 UTC 2019 : Starting execution for request: 15b7bb5d-48df-11e9-b05b-37cbe151f14e Sun Mar 17 18:04:19 UTC 2019 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /locations Sun Mar 17 18:04:19 UTC 2019 : Method request path: {} Sun Mar 17 18:04:19 UTC 2019 : Method request query string: {} Sun Mar 17 18:04:19 UTC 2019 : Method request headers: {Authorization=****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************QgxrTw} Sun Mar 17 18:04:19 UTC 2019 : Method request body before transformations: Sun Mar 17 18:04:19 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request URI: https://lambda.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-3:830442835011:function:getDeliveryLocations/invocations Sun Mar 17 18:04:19 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request headers: {x-amzn-lambda-integration-tag=15b7bb5d-48df-11e9-b05b-37cbe151f14e, Authorization=************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************46e064, X-Amz-Date=20190317T180419Z, x-amzn-apigateway-api-id=f66npkqdt6, X-Amz-Source-Arn=arn:aws:execute-api:eu-west-3:830442835011:f66npkqdt6/test-invoke-stage/GET/locations, Accept=application/json, User-Agent=AmazonAPIGateway_f66npkqdt6, X-Amz-Security-Token=FQoGZXIvYXdzEIL//////////wEaDCjYUzK2fkFwxmMskyKxA7psESYIL8x6piPZS91AzdzgF/l3zgUk9ebiYurX3dzAhdb6MeHSp952klAF9I8mO8LF/uMzV4WsIhmjeq2rvg3dVX4Mo5saxzxzcEUwBzfceseacnwM6aunfQuUSQfwp+weB+pfmPmSVhaWwfARwTSAXazjroRBZ0+fVFnKlS4o8gzPI/+Ly0Gb/AlOhIv5WUapfW6pbYJRi9UjEuApjRqFZfBBFYtdc18KX0YX0MlAlrpVpBI+vvox2jI9aNhnSEZPMDwzh8T5l9o3oeu7BWfzwhnzLe1mG1R [TRUNCATED] Sun Mar 17 18:04:19 UTC 2019 : Endpoint request body after transformations: { "email": "", "email2": "", "email3": "", "user": "", "user2": "" } Sun Mar 17 18:04:19 UTC 2019 : Sending request to https://lambda.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-3:830442835011:function:getDeliveryLocations/invocations Sun Mar 17 18:04:19 UTC 2019 : Received response. Integration latency: 471 ms Sun Mar 17 18:04:19 UTC 2019 : Endpoint response body before transformations: [{"location": ""}, {"location": ""}, {"location": ""}, {"location": ""}] Sun Mar 17 18:04:19 UTC 2019 : Endpoint response headers: {Date=Sun, 17 Mar 2019 18:04:19 GMT, Content-Type=application/json, Content-Length=72, Connection=keep-alive, x-amzn-RequestId=24c150c8-9dd8-41f5-a24c-ec9e06658cf2, x-amzn-Remapped-Content-Length=0, X-Amz-Executed-Version=$LATEST} Sun Mar 17 18:04:19 UTC 2019 : Method response body after transformations: [{"location": ""}, {"location": ""}, {"location": ""}, {"location": ""}] Sun Mar 17 18:04:19 UTC 2019 : Method response headers: {X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-5c8e8c23-0fd4bddde83818f96ae9f16b, Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*, Content-Type=application/json} Sun Mar 17 18:04:19 UTC 2019 : Successfully completed execution Sun Mar 17 18:04:19 UTC 2019 : Method completed with status: 200

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWplb.jpg)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

After a long time i figured out. The problem is you need to add Authorization to Method request header. The call from console test still does not work, but you can call the method from eg.: Postman with Authorization header and token.